# no fonts in menus in nautilus/thunar/iceweasel debian

Tags: fonts, thunar, fluxbox

i am on `debian 7.11` . I am running `Thunar` or `nautilus` or `iceweasel` in `fluxbox`, but I can see no fonts in the menus or i nthe filenames (in the case of the former 2).
[image: no fonts in Thnumar menus]
What do I need to do / what package do I need to install to get some fonts ?

The same problems occurs in all applications

Note: that the fonts do not appear at all, but I have only be able to find google results for low-quality font problems.

EDIT:
I am trying to connect to this session over `nomachineNX 3.5` linux and windows clients.

EDIT2: the problem is not present when I connect locally to that pc - it is only over NX that it appears.

Comment: Is this behavior new?

Comment: hmmm cannot tell. I have had this pc running headless for a few years. I just installed `nomachine NX 3.5` and try to connect from another pc. This is how I get this. locally I will have to connect a monitor and check.

Comment: Maybe relevant https://www.nomachine.com/AR0500591

Comment: @Bahamut unfortunately it did not help :(